# primitives as function arguments in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JS here, and have a question regarding primitive values when passed in as arguments. Say I have a simple function:

```
var first = 5;
var second = 6;

function func(){
    first+=second;
}
func();
alert(first); //outputs 11
```

So in this case the value of first becomes 11.. But if I try it by passing in first as an argument to the function, first remains 5..

```
var first = 5;
var second = 6;

function func(first){
    first+=second;
}
func(first);
alert(first); //outputs 5
```

wondering if someone could explain this to me.

Comment: Note that it has nothing to do with "primitive" types, it just about the scope in javascript.

Comment: I'm sure in couple day you'll start answer question in js... Good Luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because when you call `function first()` with no arguments, it uses the global var "first". But when you call `function first(first)`, you says to browser that now first is a local variable (only inside the function) and it doesn't make any changes to the global var `first`. Here's the code:

```
var first = 5;
var second = 6;
function func(first){
    first += second; //Local var "first" + global var "second"
    alert(first); //Local var, outputs 11
}
func(first);
alert(first); //Global var, outputs 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Due to Javascript's scoping, the scoped variable `first` is overriding the global variable first. In other words, you're adding `second` to the scoped version of `first` inside your function (which is scoped because you're declaring it inside the function), and the global version of `first` is unaffected.

If you remove the `first`'s declaration from the function, Javascript goes for the next version of `first` it can find--in this case, the global one.

Answer (score 1):

```
var first= 5;
var second= 6;

function func(first){

first+=second; // change the local first variable

}
func(first);
alert(first);//outputs 5 - the outer variable wasn't changed.
```

---

```
var first= 5; // global var
var second= 6;

function func(){ // first wasn't defined in the inner scope.

first+=second; // change the global bar

}
func();
alert(first);//outputs 11 - the outer variable was changed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark Linus got your answer right, but I want to add an important note. Primitive values in JavaScript are always passed by value, where Array's and Object's are always passed by reference. Example:

```js
var first = [ 'a', 'b' ];

function func( arr ) {
    arr.push( 'c' );
}

func( first );

alert( first.join( ',' )); // output is 'a,b,c'
```

It gets more complicated if you have Objects in Objects or Arrays. Just remember that an alteration will affect all instances in your program.